# How to do MVC in ES6 javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

1. In ES5 I create a Model-View-Controller structure by using IIFEs and reveal module pattern.

   ```
   var model = function () { ... }()
   var view = function () { ... }()
   var controller = function (model, view) { 
       view.functionname(var one);
       ......
   }(model, view)
   ```

The new block scope {}  in ES6 can replace IIFEs, but how we call the functions/methods of the model/view from the controller ?

2. To combine multiple javascripts in ES5 and avoid naming collision I use an expression:

   ```
   ;( code ...)
   ```

How can be this done in ES6 ?

Comment: `view.function(var one);` is invalid JS. `;( code ...)` does not avoid naming collision. It may solve issues with automatic semi-colon insertion. Not sure what you are asking. Also, limit your question to one question.

Comment: Why do you think calling `view.functionname(…)` becomes something else in ES6?

Comment: I updated the code, it was just as a placeholder, because I wanted to understand the concept; (code) I just wanted to say that I force the evaluation of what is inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The new block scope in ES6 can replace IIFEs

Not really. It can replace IIFEs that were merely introducing scope, but it cannot replace the module pattern - a block has no return value. Also it doesn't take any arguments. You *could* just use global variables:

```
var model, view, controller;
{
    model = {…};
}
{
    view = {…};
}
{
    let one = …;
    view.functionname(one);
    controller = {…};
}
```

But honestly that's quite weird<sup>1</sup>. There's no reason not to use the exact same revealing module pattern that we know since ES3.

<sub>1: A viable alternative would be ES6 modules, which allow circular dependencies and have better syntax for all this</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
class View {
    exampleMethod() {
        console.log("view's example method called")
    }
}

class Model {
    exampleMethod() {
        console.log("model's example method called")
    }
}

class Controller {
    constructor(view,model) {
        this.view = view
        this.model = model
        console.log("Test")
    }
    exampleMethod() {
        this.view.exampleMethod()
        this.model.exampleMethod()
    }
}

const myView = new View()
const myModel = new Model()

const myController = new Controller(myView,myModel)
myController.exampleMethod()
```

To avoid name collision in ES6 you could wrap everything into

```
(()=>{
    // Code...
})()
```